# Run module from os.system with conda environment

Tags: python

I am trying to run a module `module1` inside a python script `external_script.py`. The script is as follows:

```
run_module = 'cd ..; cd dir1; conda activate myenv; python -m module1'
os.system(run_module)
```

Then I am a bunch of import errors that seem to indicate that there's a path issue. I have specifically two issues:

- the `run.py` file of `module1` starts with a few imports of external libraries that are installed in the conda environment `myenv` but I got a `ModuleNotFoundError`. I had to install them in the current virtual environment (the one I use to run the script `external_script.py`).
- the next few lines of `module1/run.py` are imports of functions and classes from other modules located in `libs` inside `dir1`, but when I run `external_script.py` I get another `No module named 'internal_module_A'`.

Here is the structure of my files.

```
base_directory
│     
└───dir0
│       external_script.py
│
└───dir1
    │   
    └───libs
    │   └───internal_module_A
    │   └───...
    │   
    └───module1
         run.py
```

Does anyone know why I have this issue ? It seems that inside the `os.system()` command it doesn't run the file from where it is supposed to.

Note that in another case (for let's say `dir2`), the base environment was a python `venv` virtual environment), and it worked well, but not in this case when the environment was a conda environment.

Also note that I can perfectly run `module1` from the terminal with the same commands (without using `os.system()`).

Comment: Are those two lines the only lines in the script? Because you are much better off doing that with a shell script.

Comment: In fact, I would argue not to activate the Conda environment through an external command in the script, but outside the script: let the user activate the Conda environment. The user runs the script; it should ensure the relevant environment is active. Don't try and handle things within Python that are related to things outside of Python.

Comment: Further, you can't rely on the `cd ..; cd dir1` part anyway: the current working directory is the one from where the script is executed; not where the script is located. If someone runs `base_directory/dir0/external_script.py`, the `cd` command will work from `base_directory`.